# min-height pushes the content outside of div instead of growing inside div

Tags: css, reactjs

[image]I have created a simple to-do app. I am creating div for every to-do being created and set min-height for the div in case if the content grows larger than div but even after setting the min-height of div content grows outside of div. Could anyone please point out what I am missing? I have attached the screenshot of the output.

```css
App.css

body {
  background-color: rgb(238, 174, 174);
}

.App {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}


Todo.css

.Todo {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;  
    min-height: 50px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

Todo.js

import React from 'react';
import "./Todo.css"

const Todo = ({title, description}) => {
    return (
        <div className="Todo">
            <p>{title}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Todo


App.js

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Todo from './Todo';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])    // todos => to store the value, setTodos => to update the state
  const [input, setInput] = useState("")

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, input])
    setInput("")
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>To-do-app</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange = {(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} value={input} />
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Todo</button>
      </form>
      {
        todos.map(todo => {
          return <Todo title={todo} /> 
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you mean to set max-height rather than min-height? Also, what do you want to happen if the input gets too long?

Comment: As shown in screenshot, input goes out of div. Div isn't growing as input grows

Comment: Ah, the other way round to what I’d inferred. You have given .Todo a height. Did you mean to give it height: auto so it grows, I am not clear whether that is the CSS used at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - lose the `min-height` change `height: auto`

```
.Todo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the height from Todo.css(Todo class) and just keep the min-height

```
.Todo {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 50px;  
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
```